# SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I got error when creating Kafka JdbcSinkConnector (my task is to transfer data from Kafka topic to Postgres table):

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException:
>   Error deserializing Avro message for id -1

What does mean id -1?

Settings for connector:

```
{
  "name": "MVM Test",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "errors.log.enable": "true",
  "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
  "topics": [
    "mvm_test_events"
  ],
  "connection.url": "jdbc:connection",
  "connection.user": "user",
  "connection.password": "*************"
}
```

Also I described schema for (value) topic "mvm_test_events" in Control Center:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "event",
  "namespace": "mvm",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "series_storage",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "type",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "entity_id",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "processing_ts",
      "type": "double"
    },
    {
      "name": "from_ts",
      "type": "double"
    },
    {
      "name": "to_ts",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "context",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "context",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "trainName",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Error logs:

```
> [2020-01-22 06:45:10,380] ERROR Error encountered in task
> mvm-test-events-0. Executing stage 'VALUE_CONVERTER' with class
> 'io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter', where consumed record is
> {topic='mvm_test_events', partition=0, offset=14,
> timestamp=1579615711794, timestampType=CreateTime}.
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.LogReporter)
> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize
> data for topic mvm_test_events to Avro:   at
> io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:107)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:487)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:487)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:464)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:320)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
> deserializing Avro message for id -1 Caused by:
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic
> byte! [2020-01-22 06:45:10,381] ERROR
> WorkerSinkTask{id=mvm-test-events-0} Task threw an uncaught and
> unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded
> in error handler  at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:487)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:464)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:320)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize
> data for topic mvm_test_events to Avro:   at
> io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:107)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:487)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
>   ... 13 more Caused by:
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
> deserializing Avro message for id -1 Caused by:
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic
> byte! [2020-01-22 06:45:10,381] ERROR
> WorkerSinkTask{id=mvm-test-events-0} Task is being killed and will not
> recover until manually restarted
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
```

As far as I can see it tries to convert record in topic with io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter. Now should I define the schema (I described in topic settings) name in connector setting "Value converter class"?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your connector config, and the full stack trace for the error please

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, did it

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your new information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

when you use the AvroConverter in Kafka Connect to read *data that hasn't been serialised as Avro*.

So you either need to fix your producer (and serialise data correctly as Avro), or if you didn't mean to use Avro then fix your Kafka Connect connector config to use the appropriate converter.

For more information [see this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/).

*Edit*: Based on your updated question, you're intending to write as Avro, so using the AvroConverter is correct. You've not included it in your connector config so I assume it's already set in your Kafka Connect worker properties (`"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"`). 
Somehow you've got data on your topic that isn't Avro. I suggest you set up a [dead letter queue](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues/) that will route these messages to a new topic for inspection, whilst enabling your sink to continue processing messages that are Avro.

Comment: Thank a lot for answer!